# Going all-in on DNSSEC

Tags: dns, resolv.conf, dig, systemd-resolved, dnscrypt

I have been doing an effort to go full on DNSSEC on my system with the following setup:

- `dnscrypt-proxy` installed, up and running on 127.0.0.1 with `require_dnssec = true`
- systemd-resolved running, with `DNSSEC=yes` and `DNS=127.0.0.1`
- only `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in `/etc/resolv.conf`
- connected through NetworkManager to a WiFi network about which I know DHCP configuration sets 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 as DNS servers

`/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` lists 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4 below 127.0.0.1.

`resolvectl status` shows

```
DNSSEC setting: yes
DNSSEC supported: yes
Current DNS Server: 127.0.0.1
DNS Servers: 127.0.0.1
```

in the Global section, but

```
 DNSSEC setting: yes
 DNSSEC supported: yes
 Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
 DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
                           8.8.8.4
```

in my interface's section (why?).

`tcpdump` shows no activity at all on udp:53 when using a web browser, dig, or other normal usage. This I take to mean that my local dnscrypt-proxy is dealing with all DNS requests on my system. I also assume that because of the configuration settings mentioned above, I am going DNSSEC all the way.

However, from time to time the journal contains lines like:

```
Nov 30 09:10:41 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question v.dropbox.com IN SOA: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:41 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question bolt.v.dropbox.com IN DS: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:41 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question bolt.v.dropbox.com IN SOA: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:41 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question bolt.v.dropbox.com IN A: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:43 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question v.dropbox.com IN SOA: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:43 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question d.v.dropbox.com IN A: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:43 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question v.dropbox.com IN SOA: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:43 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question d.v.dropbox.com IN A: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:43 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question d2e801s7grwbqs.cloudfront.net IN SOA: failed-auxiliary
Nov 30 09:10:43 tuxifaif systemd-resolved[179937]: DNSSEC validation failed for question d2e801s7grwbqs.cloudfront.net IN A: failed-auxiliary
```

- `resolvectl query v.dropbox.com` results in the same DNSSEC validation error
- `dig v.dropbox.com` works just fine
- `dig v.dropbox.com @8.8.8.8` also works just fine (of course resulting in two lines of output for `tcpdump`)

I also checked https://dnsleaktest.com, which tells me that a lot of 172.253.x.x servers are receiving a request to resolve domain names I enter into my webbrowser. These IPs seem to be owned by Google.

So, what does this mean? Is there any (non DNSSEC) querying going on on this system?

Any insights are appreciated!

Comment: make sure  /etc/systemd/resolved.conf :

DNSStubListener=yes/no is to your liking.

Comment: resolved.conf(5) doesn't really help me in figuring out the relevance of this entry. It is set to no, but would never resultin a stub since dnscrypt is already listening on port 53. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both `dnscrypt-proxy` and `systemd-resolved` are using `127.0.0.1:53`, this should not be the case. You need to disable `systemd-resolved` as recommended by [dnscrypt-proxy wiki](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation-linux#step-2-check-what-else-is-possibly-already-listening-to-port-53), and also lock `/etc/resolv.conf` for possible changes made by your Network Manager. So, here are the steps:

- Disable `systemd-resolved`:

```bsh
sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
```

- Check if there is anything else using the same `address:port` pair as `dnscrypt-proxy`: `sudo ss -lp 'sport = :domain'`. If there are, disable them.
- If `dnscrypt-proxy` is listening on `127.0.0.1:53` and `resolv.conf` has `nameserver 127.0.0.1`, add `options edns0`(required to enable DNS Security Extensions) below the `nameserver` entry in `resolv.conf` so that it looks like:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options edns0
```

- Lock `/etc/resolv.conf` file for changes: `sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.
- You might want to restart `dnscrypt-proxy`.

Overall, the point is to make sure that:

- Only `dnscrypt-proxy` is using `127.0.0.1:53`
- `resolv.conf` has the same address used by `dnscrypt-proxy`
- `resolv.conf` is protected from changes made by other software such as your Network Manager.

Also, just because the dnsleak test shows Google IPs does not mean that the dns resolver service is operated by Google. It could be that the servers are owned by Google but operated by another entity. If you dont' want it, you can choose a different resolver from [dnscrypt-proxy public resolvers list](https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-resolvers/blob/master/v2/public-resolvers.md). Make sure that `dnssec` support is present for the selected resolver. I personally use dnscrypt.eu resolvers, which are no-log, no-filter, non-google and dnssec-enabled.

References:

- https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/Installation-linux
- https://github.com/DNSCrypt/dnscrypt-proxy/wiki/systemd

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. I indeed needed to simply read the `dnscrypt-proxy` documentation in more detail... Things seem to be working as expected now.